# Check if image source is equal to an image

Tags: javascript, html

My current code exists as:

```
<img id="fixedScreenimg" src="img/fixedScreen.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
<script>
    function pictureChange(){
        if(fixedScreenimg.src == "img/homeScreen.png"){
            document.getElementById("fixedScreenimg").src="img/fixedScreen.jpg");
        }else{
            document.getElementByID("fixedScreenimg").src="img/homeScreen.png");
        }
    }
</script>
```

As  you can see, I'm attempting to check whether the image source of an element matches a given path to an image, and if so, change the result of the image changing when a button is pressed. However, this doesn't seem to work.

I've attempted to use getAttribute and the like.

Any pointers?

Thanks.

Comment: `fixedScreenimg=document.getElementById("fixedScreenimg");`

Comment: What did you use to debug your code? I saw a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )` at a specified line number and ones fixed a `Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementByID is not a function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few errors:

- `ID` instead of `Id` in `getElementById` function.
- Two, unnecessary closing brackets inside if condition.

```js
var elem = document.getElementById('fixedScreenimg'),
    btn = document.getElementById('btn');

function pictureChange() {
  if (elem.src == "img/homeScreen.png") {
    document.getElementById("fixedScreenimg").src = "img/fixedScreen.jpg";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("fixedScreenimg").src = "img/homeScreen.png";
  }
  console.log(elem.src);
}

btn.addEventListener('click', pictureChange);
```

```html
<img id="fixedScreenimg" src="img/fixedScreen.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
<button id='btn'>Change src</button>
```

Comment: Yup, it was the typo. Thanks! I'll accept this when the 10 mins are up.

Comment: @ocelot I've added a button and a function binded to it.

Answer (score 0):

You added a bracket at the end of your lines

```
document.getElementById("fixedScreenimg").src="img/fixedScreen.jpg";
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually are adding a closing bracket `)`

Try the following:

```
 function pictureChange(){

    var elem = document.getElementById("fixedScreenimg");

    if(elem.src === "img/homeScreen.png"){
        elem.src="img/fixedScreen.jpg";
    }else{
        elem.src="img/homeScreen.png";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first declare what is `fixedScreenimg` and the brackets at the 2 statements

```
<img id="fixedScreenimg" src="img/fixedScreen.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
<script>
    function pictureChange(){
        var fixedScreenimg = document.getElementById("fixedScreenimg");
        if(fixedScreenimg.src == "img/homeScreen.png"){
            fixedScreenimg.src="img/fixedScreen.jpg";
        }else{
            fixedScreenimg.src="img/homeScreen.png";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with single line if condition

```
function pictureChange() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("fixedScreenimg");

  elem.src = (elem.src == "img/homeScreen.png") ? "img/fixedScreen.jpg" : "img/homeScreen.png";
}
```

```html
<img id="fixedScreenimg" src="img/fixedScreen.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
```